# Storing Movie show times in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

The application is for showing which cinemas are showing a particular **movie** and their **show timings**.

The Movie Table :

```
info about movie
+----------+----------------------+--------------+
| movie_id | movie_name           | release_date |
+----------+----------------------+--------------+
  M1            Movie A                 2013/4/4
  M2            Movie B                 2013/4/4
  M3            Movie C                 2013/4/4
```

The Cinema Table:

```
info about cinema. One cinema can be showing multiple movies at a time

+-----------+---------------+-----------+
| cinema_id | cinema_name   | address   |
+-----------+---------------+-----------+
  C1           Cinema A       #address1
  C2           Cinema B       #address2
```

The Current_movies Table:

```
Table storing which cinema showing which movies.(Many to many relationship).
+-----------+----------+
| cinema_id | movie_id |
+-----------+----------+
  C1           M1
  C1           M2
  C2           M1
  C2           M2
  C2           M3
```

**Problem**

I am not able to figure out **how to store show timings**.

Show timings means starting time of the movie. For example: 2:40, 5:00, 8:30 etc .

I thought of doing it like this.

```
+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| cinema_id | movie_id | show_time_one | show_time_two | show_time_three |
+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

But felt this is not the correct way.

Please suggest.

Also please suggest if there is some optimizations for current three tables.

**UPDATE**

You are welcome to down vote the question if it does not seem appropriate to you.
But please take a minute too to comment what's wrong with the question and how can I improve it to make it answerable .

Comment: Please explain what a `show_time` is:  Length of media?  Date and time at which a film is scheduled to show?  How many times it has shown?

Comment: Thanks for response.Show time is starting time of movie which will be in format 2:00 or 5:00 or 8:00 etc. hope that explains.

Comment: Do you record each distinct showing separately?  That is, do you show Monday Aug 12, 7pm, Tuesday Aug 13, 7pm, Wed Aug 14 7pm?  Or do you record "7pm" and assume it shows every day at that time? Or somethhing different?

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for reminding me of this aspect which I had missed. For now I would like to assume 7pm every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a showtime table:

```
  cinema_id | movie_id | showtime
```

All three of these columns, taken together, make up the primary key of this table. The showtime column could be a TIME datatype

You might have rows like this in that table:

```
  cinema_id | movie_id | showtime
  C1          M1         14:30
  C1          M1         17:00
  C1          M1         20:30
```

You can use the TIME_FORMAT function to convert your stored times to am/pm etc.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format

The design principle here is called *normalization*, about which you should read.

Comment: like this the table will be full with redundancy

Comment: Thank you @Ollie Jones. It seems a good idea to have a showtime table with three cols. Only doubt I have here is repeating C1 and M1 three times or may be four times . So I will wait for other answers too  with hope to get better solution if there is any.

Comment: You cant avoid repeating cinema_id OR movie_id in the showtime table it´s a Many to Many relation ship

Comment: There are approximately 40,000 commercial cinema screens in the USA. With your assumption of 3 showings on each screen, this means 120,000 rows in your table.  Let's be generous and give 100 bytes per row. This means your table will contain 12 megabytes of data.  If you denormalize it to save space, you can get it down to maybe half that, so you've saved six megabytes.  Disk space on amazon web services costs about US$120.00 per gigabyte per year.  So, denormalizing this table to save space will save you $0.72 per year.  And, as soon as a cinema shows a film four times a day, you're hosed.

Comment: Would you please clear one more doubt ? How to store if movie is still running in at least one cinema or not ? Will it be good idea to add a column movie_status in current_movies table ?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake.  AWS storage costs $1.20 a gigabyte a year, not $120. So the cost of normalizing is $0.0072 a year. d'oh!

Comment: You should be able to create a query to determine how many cinemas are showing a particular movie. That query will probably be fast enough to avoid the need for denormalizing using a `status` column.

Answer (score -1):

make it like this :

```
cinema_id |  movie_id
```

and then another table "showTime":

```
movie_id | show_1 | show2 | show3
```

like this it less redendancy and normalized

Comment: Cinema_id can not be removed because show timings can be different for different combination of movie_id and cinema_id.

Comment: why? whn u use the table cinema_id | movie_id and then u make the table without cinema_id it's te perfect solution

Comment: -1. Repeated columns with the same sort of data are denormalized, not normalized.